# pop-up a window when the user clicks a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my HTML code:

```html
<p style="align-content: center">
  <A style="align-content: center" HREF="newpopup.html" onClick="return popup(this, 'stevie')">my popup</A><br>
</p>
<p align="center">
  <input type="button" onclick="popup(this, 'about') " value="CLICK HERE">
</p>
```

And JavaScript:

```js
function popup(mylink, windowname)
{
  if (! window.focus)
    return true;
  var href;
  if (typeof(mylink) == 'string')
    href=mylink;
  else 
    href=mylink.href;
  window.open(href, windowname, 'width=400,height=200,scrollbars=yes');
  return false;
}
```

My button 'CLICK HERE' pops-up a window but it is empty. I want my button to work just like above URL link 'my popup'.

So I want to open the contents of `newpopup.html` in my pop-up window on a button click.

My URL link for pop-up is working fine, I want the button to work thesame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mylink` (the button's `this`) isn't a string, so you try to open `mylink.href`:

```
if (typeof(mylink) == 'string')
  href = mylink;
else 
  href = mylink.href;
```

But buttons don't *have* `href` properties, so it's as if you wrote:

```
window.open(undefined, 'about', 'width=400,height=200,scrollbars=yes');
```

which opens a blank page, as expected. If you want to open the same page as the link, use:

```
onclick="popup('newpopup.html', 'about');"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple piece of code:

```
<script>
   function fullwindowpopup(){
      window.open("newpopup.html","bfs","fullscreen,scrollbars")
   }
</script>
```

---

```
<center>
    <form>
        <input type="button" onClick="fullwindowpopup()" value="CLICK HERE">
    </form>
</center>
```

Comment: What does the second parameter "bfs" mean here?

Answer (score 0):

Pop ups can be tricky if you want them to "float" above your html page. This can be obtained by using an absolute placement to place a "filter" and the required frame over your current page. Usually I go for something like this:

HTML

```
<body>
     ...
     <div class='myPopup'>
           <iframe src='http://www.myurl.com' id='popup-frame'>
           </iframe> <!-- /#popup-frame -->
     </div> <!-- /.myPopup -->
     ...
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.myPopup {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #A8A8A8;
    opacity: 0.4;
    display: none;
    z-index: 100;
}

#popup-frame {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}
```

Comment: i dont want just a pop-up, i want pop-up with cross button on the right,scrollbar on the right and full screen. so i choose window pop-up but dont know how to implement this in button

Comment: @SidJj I'm not here to code for you. The provided code will provide you with the basic framework to build a pop-up around.

Answer (score 0):

[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59558672/12153058) Check this example.

The `javascript` is below

```
<script>
        function openPopup() {
            document.getElementById("boxPopup").style.display = "block";
        }

        function closePopup() {
            document.getElementById("boxPopup").style.display = "none";
        }
        // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
        window.onclick = function (event) {
            var modal = document.getElementById('boxPopup');
            if (event.target == modal) {
                closePopup();
            }
        }

    </script>
```